# Golang exec.Command Output blank(no error)

Tags: sqlite, go

I am attempting to run a sqlite3 command from within Go, to do a simple query (I completly understand there are other ways to access sqlite from go, but thats not the issue here)

```
func sqliteTest(){
    cmd:=exec.Command("/usr/bin/sqlite3", " /home/chadg/Downloads/testDb.db 'select * from testTable;'")
    fmt.Println("Command String:",cmd.String())
    out,err:=cmd.CombinedOutput()
    if err!=nil{
        fmt.Println("Error Accessing Database:",err.Error(),string(out))
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("Result Length:",len(out))
    fmt.Println("Result:",string(out))

}
```

Running this gives me this output:

```
Command String: /usr/bin/sqlite3  /home/chadg/Downloads/testDb.db 'select * from testTable;'
Result Length: 0
Result: 

Process finished with exit code 0
```

However if I run the same command by hand:

```
$ /usr/bin/sqlite3  /home/chadg/Downloads/testDb.db 'select * from testTable;'
testName|testValue
```

Have certainly run into many issues when running commands from within go, but there is always an error generated, but this time, there is no error, but the result from stdout and stderr seems to both be empty.

EDIT:
Single quotes vs double quotes doesn't change anything

```
cmd:=exec.Command("/usr/bin/sqlite3", " /home/chadg/Downloads/testDb.db \"select * from testTable;\"")
```

still returns an empty output, but works as expected from the command line.

Comment: `cmd:=exec.Command("/usr/bin/sqlite3", " /home/chadg/Downloads/testDb.db","'select * from testTable;'")` though i am unsure about the single quotes around the sql

Comment: The single quotes are used from the command line (see where I ran it by hand), I also tried escaping double quotes to see if that changed anything. Same result, runs from the terminal, but gets empty output when run from Go.

Comment: take care to the leadng space in your path `" /home/chadg/Downloads/testDb.db 'select * from testTable;'"`

Comment: you have to split the two arguments, the path and the sql query.

Comment: @mh-cbon thank, that was a copy/paste error, removed it and still didnt change anything.

Comment: @mh-cbon     I even tried that, but I had left the quotes, and this causes an error.  But split in two, and removing the quoting works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arguments in [`exec.Command`](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec#Command) should be passed as separate strings.

```
cmd := exec.Command("/usr/bin/sqlite3", "/home/chadg/Downloads/testDb.db", "select * from testTable;")
```

As for the behavior you're observing:

When `sqlite3` is started non-interactively with 1 argument, it treats that as the database file name and reads the query from `stdin`, but `cmd.CombinedOutput()` closes `stdin`, resulting in an empty output.

Comment: Yep... Thank. I had tried separating them, but I had left the sql argument quoted, and this causes an error. Thanks!